# user_id принимает значение None после вызова функции (telebot, sqlite3)

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот, sqlite3

Делаю бота в телеграм через библиотеку telebot. Данная функция достает из базы данных SQL3 город проживания, который раннее выбрал пользователь в переменную city_living.

```
def get_city_living(user_id: int):
    with sqlite3.connect('server.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            first_seen TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
            city_living TEXT
            )
            ''')
        cursor.execute('SELECT city_living FROM users WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,))
        city = cursor.fetchone()
        return city[0]
```

В результате вызова функции возникает ошибка

```
File "<string>", line 376, in 
bot_message 
File "<string>", line 86, in 
get_city_living
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not 
subscriptable
```

Line 86 это последняя строка кода. Как думаете, почему у user_id значение None? Я перед вызовом функции прописывал user_id=callback.message.from_user.id.
Кстати, заметил, что если последние две строки закомментировать и добавить `print(user_id)`, то вначале в терминале user_id выводится, а уже после вызова функции преобретает значение None (исходя из текста ошибки). Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вывести саму city и посмотреть ее содержимое. Есть вероятность что она просто пустая. И уберите запятую в строчке 84 после user_id.